# What does 301 in kernel version signify?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I have been using my fc22 machine for a while and wanted to learn more about kernels and how to build kernels.
I wanted to know about what 301 on kernel version signifies. 
Is it some kind of security patch or additional modules?

Output of `uname -a` :
`Linux localhost.localdomain 4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 21 13:10:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: You should consider switching to a supported version of fedora too

Answer (score 0):

The `301` is a version number assigned by a distribution's kernel package maintainer. This number is typically rev'ed when the kernel package maintainer incorporates distribution-specific support or fixes, or backports specific features from a later kernel.